# Reverse engineering an Event from its ABI

Tags: solidity, struct, abi

I'm trying to reverse engineer a smart contract interface from its ABI but I'm stuck with this event definition (the struct in particular). Does anyone know how that event would look like in solidity? Here's the ABI

```js
{
  anonymous: !1,
  inputs: [
    {
      indexed: !0,
      internalType: "uint256",
      name: "_axieId",
      type: "uint256",
    },
    {
      components: [
        { internalType: "uint256", name: "x", type: "uint256" },
        { internalType: "uint256", name: "y", type: "uint256" },
      ],
      indexed: !1,
      internalType: "struct AxieGenetics.Genes",
      name: "_genes",
      type: "tuple",
    },
  ],
  name: "AxieEvolved",
  type: "event",
},
```

The best I've been able to do is

```
abstract contract SmartContract {

  struct AxieGeneticsGenes {
    uint256 x;
    uint256 y;
  }

  event AxieEvolved(
    uint256 indexed _axieId,
    AxieGeneticsGenes _genes
  );
}
```

But `AxieGeneticsGenes` is not the same as `AxieGenetics.Genes` as shown in the ABI. How do I created that nested struct definition?

Comment: The actual name of that struct is `Genes`, and `AxieGenetics` is just the library or abstract contract where it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

As it usually happens, after posting a question I'm able to figure it out by myself. You can use a smart contract as a way of grouping related structs like this

```
abstract contract AxieGenetics {
  struct Genes {
    uint256 x;
    uint256 y;
  }
}

abstract contract SmartContract {
  event AxieEvolved(
    uint256 indexed _axieId,
    AxieGenetics.Genes _genes
  );
}
```

Comment: it is an anonymous event, you won't be able to filter logs and query it on the blockchain

Comment: also this ABI doesn't look like from Ethereum, in Ethereum we have boolean fields using `true` and `false` values, not `!0` and `!1`

Comment: @Nulik that's right, it's from an Ethereum sidechain called Ronin that's supposed to be EVM compatible